# Escaping pipe character in rsh

Tags: bash, rsh

I am trying to run this bash command, but I cant get around the "|" pipe character

`rsh -l user machine "echo "PORTS = 123|456|789" >> conf.cfg"`

Getting:

`bash: 456 >> conf.cfg: No such file or directory`

`bash: 789: command not found`

Would you know how I can echo `PORTS = 123|456|789` into a remote file ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just escape the pipes and the quotes:

```
rsh -l user machine "echo \"PORTS = 123\|456\|789\" >> conf.cfg"
```